# Problems returning to initial state after state change

Tags: vhdl, fsm

I'm just starting out with VHDL and it seems that after I make the initial change from state `NTIME` to `SET_TIME`, I can't return back to `NTIME` in order to be able to change back to `SET_ALARM`.

I have checked the signal before my `case`-block and it seems to be correctly created and received. But I seem to be simply stuck in `SET_TIME`. The change from `NTIME` to `SET_TIME` occurs when the button with the encoding `'0001'` is received. When this signal is received a second time, the state is supposed to return to the original state of `NTIME`. A similar situation is seen with the input `'0010'` for state `SET_ALARM`.

Here is what I have so far:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity controller is
  port(
    btn : in  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    sw : in  std_logic_vector(0 downto 0);
    o_mins, o_secs, o_wmins : out integer range 0 to 59;
    o_hours, o_whours : out integer range 0 to 23;
    alarm : out std_logic;
    state : out std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
    clk : in  std_logic;
    reset : in  std_logic
  );
end controller;

architecture Behavioral of controller is

  component trigger_gen is
    generic(Delta : integer);
    port(
      clk   : in std_logic;
      reset : in std_logic;
      trigger : out std_logic
    );
  end component trigger_gen;

  -- pro Viertelsekunde einen Takt lang '1'
  signal fasttrigger : std_logic;
  -- fasttrigger wird zurueckgesetzt, wenn BTN2 oder BTN3 gedrueckt werden
  signal fasttimer_reset : std_logic;
  -- pro Sekunde einen Takt lang '1'
  signal sectrigger : std_logic;

  signal hours, whours     : integer range 0 to 23;
  signal secs, mins, wmins : integer range 0 to 59;

  -- fuer Flankenerkennung der Taster
  signal btn_shift : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
  signal btn_triggered : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);

  type state_type is (NTIME, SET_TIME, SET_ALARM, error);
  signal current_state : state_type;

begin
  fasttimer_reset <= reset or
        btn_triggered(2) or btn_triggered(3);

  fasttimer : trigger_gen
    generic map(11)
    port map(clk, fasttimer_reset, fasttrigger);

  sectimer : trigger_gen
    generic map(13)
    port map(clk, reset, sectrigger);

  FSM : process(clk, reset)
    variable next_state : state_type;
  begin
    if reset = '1' then
      hours  <= 0;
      mins   <= 0;
      secs   <= 0;
      whours <= 0;
      wmins  <= 0;
      alarm  <= '0';
      current_state <= NTIME;
    elsif clk'event and clk = '1' then
      for i in 0 to 3 loop
        btn_shift(i) <= btn(i);
        btn_triggered(i) <= not btn_shift(i) and btn(i);
      end loop;

        -- TODO: Zaehle Uhr hoch
        IF secs <= 58 THEN 
            secs <= secs + 1;
        ELSE
            secs <= 0;
            IF mins <= 58 THEN
                mins <= mins + 1;
            ELSE
                mins <= 0;
                IF hours <= 22 THEN
                    hours <= hours + 1; 
                ELSE
                    hours <= 0;
                END IF;
            END IF;
        END IF;




      -- TODO: Pruefe, ob Alarm ausgeloest werden muss
      IF hours = whours AND mins = wmins AND sw(0) = '1' THEN
        alarm <= '1';
      END IF;
      case current_state is
        -- Zustand Time
        when NTIME =>
            IF btn_triggered(0) = '1'  THEN
              REPORT "Going to set time";
              next_state := SET_TIME;
            ELSIF btn_triggered(1) = '1' THEN
            REPORT "Going to set Alarm";
              next_state := SET_ALARM;
            END IF;

        -- Zustand SetTime
        when SET_TIME =>
            IF btn_triggered(0) = '1' THEN
                next_state := NTIME;
            END IF;

            IF  btn_triggered(2) = '1' THEN
                REPORT "SETTING MINUTES IN TIME";
                IF mins <= 58 THEN
                    mins <= mins + 1;
                ELSE
                    mins <= 0;
                END IF;
            ELSIF btn_triggered(3) = '1' THEN
                REPORT "SETTING HOURS IN TIME";
                IF hours <= 22 THEN
                    hours <= hours + 1;
                ELSE
                    hours <= 0;
                END IF;
            END IF;

        -- Zustand SetAlarm
        when SET_ALARM =>
            IF btn_triggered(1) = '1' THEN
                next_state := NTIME;
            END IF;
            IF btn_triggered(2) = '1' THEN
                REPORT "SETTING MINUTES IN ALARM";
                IF wmins <= 58 THEN
                    wmins <= wmins + 1;
                ELSE
                    wmins <= 0;
                END IF;
            ELSIF btn_triggered(3) = '1' THEN
                REPORT "SETTING HOURS IN ALARM";
                IF whours <= 22 THEN
                    whours <= whours + 1;
                ELSE
                    whours <= 0;
                END IF;
            END IF;

            next_state := NTIME;

          -- Illegale Zustaende
        when others =>
          next_state := NTIME;
      end case;

      current_state <= next_state;
    end if;
  end process FSM;

  o_hours  <= hours;
  o_mins   <= mins;
  o_secs   <= secs;
  o_whours <= whours;
  o_wmins  <= wmins;

  with current_state select
    state <= "00" when NTIME,
             "01" when SET_TIME,
             "10" when SET_ALARM,
             "11" when others;
end architecture Behavioral;
```

I'm not sure if it is just a fundamental misunderstanding of VHDL or perhaps just a typo.

Here is my Test Bench:

```
-- vim: set syntax=vhdl ts=8 sts=2 sw=2 et:

LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
USE ieee.numeric_std.ALL;

ENTITY tb_controller IS
END tb_controller;

ARCHITECTURE behavior OF tb_controller IS

  COMPONENT controller IS PORT (
    btn                     : IN  std_logic_vector(3 DOWNTO 0);
    sw                      : IN  std_logic_vector(0 DOWNTO 0);
    o_mins, o_secs, o_wmins : OUT integer RANGE 0 TO 59;
    o_hours, o_whours       : OUT integer RANGE 0 TO 23;
    alarm                   : OUT std_logic;
    clk                     : IN  std_logic;
    reset                   : IN  std_logic );
  END COMPONENT;

  SIGNAL tb_clk:     STD_LOGIC := '0';
  SIGNAL tb_BTN:     STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0) := (OTHERS => '0');
  SIGNAL tb_SW:      STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(0 DOWNTO 0) := "0";
  SIGNAL tb_ring:    STD_LOGIC;
  SIGNAL tb_reset:   STD_LOGIC;
  SIGNAL tb_secs:    integer RANGE 0 to 59;
  SIGNAL tb_mins:    integer RANGE 0 to 59;
  SIGNAL tb_hours:   integer RANGE 0 to 23;
  SIGNAL tb_wmins:   integer RANGE 0 to 59;
  SIGNAL tb_whours:  integer RANGE 0 to 23;

BEGIN

  -- Generiere Wecker-Takt 2^13Hz = 8192Hz
  tb_clk <= NOT tb_clk after 61035 ns;

  -- Generiere Reset
  tb_reset <= '1', '0' after 250 us;

  -- Stellen der Uhrzeit:
  tb_BTN(0) <= '1' after 10 sec, '0' after 27 sec;  -- set time
  tb_BTN(1) <= '1' after 28 sec, '0' after 38 sec;  -- set alarm
  tb_BTN(2) <= '1' after 11 sec, '0' after 22250 ms, '1' after 29 sec, '0' after 32750 ms;  -- set Minutes
  tb_BTN(3) <= '1' after 23 sec, '0' after 26 sec, '1' after 34 sec, '0' after 37250 ms;  -- set Houres
  tb_SW(0)  <= '1' after 40 sec;  --activate alarm clock

TB : PROCESS 
BEGIN
  WAIT FOR 1 sec;
  IF (tb_ring = '1') THEN
    WAIT FOR 1 sec;
    ASSERT FALSE REPORT "Simulation completed." SEVERITY FAILURE;
  END IF;
END PROCESS;

  -- Instantiierung des Weckers IN der Testbench
  DeviceUnderTest:controller
    PORT MAP(
      clk       => tb_clk,
      btn       => tb_BTN,
      sw        => tb_SW,
      o_mins    => tb_mins,
      o_secs    => tb_secs,
      o_wmins   => tb_wmins,
      o_hours   => tb_hours,
      o_whours  => tb_whours,
      alarm     => tb_ring,
      reset     => tb_reset );

END ARCHITECTURE;
```

Comment: It's not going to solve your problem, but you don't need the `next_state` variable; just assign directly to `current_state`. Is this simulation or real hardware, and are your buttons debounced?

Comment: It is just a simulation at this point. It also seems to be the case that my buttons are debounced in the test bench. i will edit the post to include my test bench as well.

Comment: Does something improve if you initialize `btn_shift` and `btn_triggered`  to 0 when reset is 1? I think that the simulator will set them to X (undefined) for the very first clock cycle after the reset goes to 0

Comment: you need to add (at least) the description of `trigger_gen` inorder to provide us with a [mcve]. Else we are not able to reproduce your problem in simulation.

Comment: If your inputs to btn is a push button switch, then your double sampling, ie: "btn_triggered(i) <= not btn_shift(i) and btn(i);" is probably not sufficient.

Comment: I would restart your problem.   Draw a picture.   Separate out the pieces of hardware.   Since the count is in base 10, I prefer to separate out each digit,  This way, I can display each digit directly rather than doing a larger conversion.

Comment: Without a [mcve] those who could answer are floundering around noticing things. Adding a trigger_gen entity/architecture [we see there is only one occurrence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKo8B.png) of `btn_triggered(0) = '1'` also required for the state transition from SET_TIME to NTIME.